# Abaqus python script with pythonnet

Tags: c#, python, .net, abaqus, python.net

I'm trying to create a plugin for Abaqus using python. I've managed to set it up, and can successfully run a simple plugin example.

Now in my script, I want to access a .NET dll compiled from a C++/CLI project. For this I've used *pythonnet*. This allows me reference the dll, and call its function.

The script I made works successfully when launched with:

- Stand-alone Python 6.7.15 (not related to Abaqus python)
- Abaquse's Python (6.7.3) located in `ABQ_DIR\6.14-1\tools\SMApy\python2.7` , launched directly without opening Abaqus.

**BUT**, when I launch my plugin from Abaqus, the weirdest thing happens, Abaqus just closes without any error message.

After a little bit debugging, I found that its caused by the line:

```
import clr
```

The `clr` module (from pythonnet) is what lets me reference a .NET dll.

If I open Abaqus, and type `import clr` in the script/command panel, Abaqus just closes without warning...

If I go to `ABQ_DIR\Commands` I find a file called `abaqus.rpy`, which is some sort of log file. The last line there is:

```
cliCommand("""import clr""")
```

I really don't know what to make of this. Does Abaqus not want me to use exactly that module...?

Comment: What version 6.x of Abaqus are you using?

Comment: @Echeban Probably 6.14